# $.when().then() not working with nested ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to scroll the page to a dynamic `div` that is created by the an ajax call.

When `#divnotifications div` clicked (below), I make the first ajax call that adds the `Post` details, then within this ajax call, another ajax call is made to add the related comments to the div.

The part explained so far works great. Then, I use `$.when().then()` to scroll to a div item created based on the ajax calls. However, the page does not scroll to the element that was created by `LoadCommentsForPost` ajax call.

Did I get the logic of `$.when().then()` wrong?

```
    $(document).on('click', '#divnotifications div', function (event) {
          event.preventDefault();
          $.ajax({
              //other details
              success: function (postid) {
                  $.when(DisplayPostWithFullDetails(postid)).then(function () {                            
                      //scroll to the content created by 
                      //LoadCommentsForPost function nested 
                      //inside DisplayPostWithFullDetails
                  });
              }
          });                
    });

    function DisplayPostWithFullDetails(postId) {
         $.ajax({
            //other details
            success: function (post) {
                //The code to build the div to display the post -- working fine
                LoadCommentsForPost(post.PostId);                

            }
        });
    }

    function LoadCommentsForPost(postid) {
        $.ajax({
            //other details
            success: function (response) {
                var comments = JSON.parse(response);
                DisplayComments(comments);//builds the div to display the comments - working fine
            }
        });
    }
```

**UPDATED CODE**

After receiving some feedback, I ended up with the following code. However, it is still not working. It works only if I add some delay to make sure the div is loaded:

```
    $(document).on('click', '#divnotifications div', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            //other ajax stuff
             success: function (postid) {
                  DisplayPostWithFullDetails(postid).done(function () {
                          setTimeout(function () {
                              var scrollto = $("div[data-" + type.toLowerCase() +  "displayform='" + relateditem + "']").offset().top;
                              $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: scrollto }, 600);
                          }, 500);
                  });
             }
        });
    });

    function DisplayPostWithFullDetails(postId) {
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        return $.ajax({
            //other ajax stuff
            success: function (post) {
                post = JSON.parse(post);
                //display the post details

                LoadCommentsForPost(post.PostId);
            }
        });
    }

    function LoadCommentsForPost(postid) {
        var promise = new $.Deferred();
        jQuery.support.cors = true;
        $.ajax({
            //other ajax stuff
            success: function (response) {
                var comments = JSON.parse(response);
                DisplayComments(comments);//this is not ajax 

                promise.resolve('loadedcomments');
            }
        });

        return promise;
    }
```

Comment: `DisplayPostWithFullDetails` returns undefined, it should return the ajax request(promise) and the same for `LoadCommentsForPost` method

Comment: shouldn't have to use `JSON.parse()` if your headers are set at server properly or you use `dataType` option. jQuery will do it for you

Comment: @charlietfl I use `dataType: 'json',` and can run ajax and display everything properly.

Comment: @erkaner See your update, double check my response..
You inverted the LoadCommentsForPost and The DisplayPostWithFullDetails behavior, $.deferred should be in the first ajax call in order to "Resolve" the promise, when the second ajax call has finished. Actually you are returning a promise that is resolved when the first ajax is resolved but never using the LoadCommentsForPost promise Or you use deffered in both but you need to resolve the first promise when the second promise is already resolved.

Comment: @erkaner Just see how it should work (set timeout is emulating your ajax calls) 
https://jsfiddle.net/jv7rrppm/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did I get the logic of $.when().then() wrong?

No, but you are NOT returning the promise so you can't use the promise functions like .then().

UPDATE:

> I use $.when().then() to scroll to a div item created based on the ajax calls. However, the page does not scroll to the element that was created by LoadCommentsForPost ajax call.

For me this means that you need to wait that both ajax calls are resolved.

This fiddle show how it should work emulating the ajax call using setTimeout [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jv7rrppm/2/).

Your code may look similar to:

```
function DisplayPostWithFullDetails(postId) {
   var promise = new $.Deferred();
   $.ajax({
       //other details
        success: function (post) {
           //The code to build the div to display the post -- working fine
           LoadCommentsForPost(post.PostId).then(function() {
               promise.resolve();
           });                

        }
    });
    return promise;
}

function LoadCommentsForPost(postid) {
    return $.ajax({
        //other details
        success: function (response) {
            var comments = JSON.parse(response);
            DisplayComments(comments);//builds the div to display the comments - working fine
        }
    });
}
```

Now when you execute the function DisplayPostWithFullDetails it return a promise. 
So you can use .then() method;

```
DisplayPostWithFullDetails(postid)).then(function () {});
```

or...

```
var promise = DisplayPostWithFullDetails(postid);
promise.then(function(data){});
```

Also the major advantage of use $.when() is that you can execute the .then() method when all the promises that you pass to it are resolved.

There are not need to use it when you are waiting for a single promise.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I followed your approach but still works the same way, please see my updated in OP.

Comment: it worked finally, thanks for your willingness to help me out !

Comment: Glad to help :) hope you learn something, know how promises work is very useful

Answer (score 5):

> Did I get the logic of $.when().then() wrong?

Yes, you need to `return` a promise from the functions if you want to use the function with `$.when`:

```
function DisplayPostWithFullDetails(postId) {
     return $.ajax({...
//   ^^^^^^
```

That said, wrapping a single promise in `$.when` is useless.

```
$.when(DisplayPostWithFullDetails(postid)).then(function () {
```

should just be:

```
DisplayPostWithFullDetail(postid).then(function () {
```

Comment: can you give an example? also the return from the nested one?

Comment: @erkaner `function DisplayPostWithFullDetails(postId) {
         return $.ajax({...}); }`

Comment: still working the same way, I do not need `return $.ajax` in the sub ajax calls, right?

Comment: only for the DisplayPostWithFullDetails

Comment: @erkaner, yes you should return a promise in both ajax calls if you are going to interact with your last ajax call in the .then() see my answer below.

Comment: @zzzzBov thanks for your answer, but still works the same way, please see my updated in OP.

Comment: @erkaner, rather than continuing to throw code at the problem, please use words to describe the behavior you'd like to achieve.

Comment: He already told with words whats happening, the .then is executed before all the ajax call are resolved. because he is using only the promise of the first call (That is resolved inmediatly after calling the second ajax call, but never waiting for it). 

he miss used my code example :/