# execute statement after ajax call success function completes

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to execute statement after ajax success callback is completed. But inside my success callback i am writing another `$.when...then` syntax.

I have tried using `.done(function(){ .... });` and `complete` function. but nothing works for me.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",       //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb          
    url: pageURL + 'GetInitialData',        // Location of the service
    data: '{ "Id": "' + QueryString["ID"] + '"}',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",     // content type sent to server
    dataType: "json",   //Expected data format from server
    processdata: true,  //True or False                
    success: function (result) {//On Successful service call
        bindUpdateValue(result.d);
    },
    complete: function (data) {
        console.log("Cleaning Staerted");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("successAssignColors");
        console.log("Cleaning Done");
    }
});

function bindUpdateValue(data) {
    $.when(BindClipartNameDDL()).then(function () { 
    .
    .
    // Some Code    
    .
    MakeAnotherAjaxCall(); // This function makes another ajax call
    ..
    //Some Code
    });
}

function MakeAnotherAjaxCall(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",       
        url: pageURL + 'PASS',      
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",     
        dataType: "json", 
        processdata: true,  
        success: function (result) {
            // SOme Code
        }   
    }); 
}

function BindClipartNameDDL() {
var DefferedObject = new $.Deferred();
MakeAjaxRequest('POST', pageURL + 'GetClipartNameList', '{}').done(function (result) {
    var ddlClipartName = $('#ddlClipartName');
    $.each(result.d, function (index, item) {
        ddlClipartName.append(
        $('<option/>', {
            value: item.ClipartName,
            text: item.ClipartName,
            selected: null
        })
    );
    });
    DefferedObject.resolve();
});
return DefferedObject.promise();
}
```

My problem is `sessionStorage.removeItem("successColors");` is getting executed at the time same when function `bindUpdateValue` is getting executed.

I want to execute `sessionStorage.removeItem("successColors");` this line after completion of function `bindUpdateValue`.

Comment: What is `BindClipartNameDDL`? How does it relate to the ajax call? Why are you using `$.when` on a single promise (presuming that `BindClipartNameDDL` returns a promise)? (As its job is to aggregate promises.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder : i have edited the question as per your query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me - adding a `.done` callback after `$.when` in function `bindUpdateValue`

```
function bindUpdateValue(data) {
    $.when(BindClipartNameDDL()).then(function () { 
    .
    .
    // Some Code    
    .
    MakeAnotherAjaxCall(); // This function makes another ajax call
    ..
    //Some Code
    }).done(function () {
        console.log("Cleaning Staerted");
        sessionStorage.removeItem("successAssignColors");
        console.log("Cleaning Done");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
  function FirstAjaxCall(){  
     var promise = new $.Deferred();

     $.ajax({
          //other details         
        success: function (result) {//On Successful service call
            BindClipartNameDDL().then(function () { 
                // Some Code    
                MakeAnotherAjaxCall(); // This function makes another ajax call
                //Some Code
                 promise.resolve();
            });
        }
     });
     return promise;
  }

  FirstAjaxCall().then(function () { 
         sessionStorage.removeItem("successColors"); 
  });
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29950249/1845408

Comment: I have added `return` keyword in function `MakeAnotherAjaxCall`. but it does not work. please check question edit

Comment: @Shaggy did you try putting this `sessionStorage.removeItem("successAssignColors");` at the end of `function bindUpdateValue(data) {}`